# PGP encryption in PHP (Windows)

Tags: php, windows, pgp

I'm having a problem with GPG encrpytion. Can you please help me with it?

It does not encrpyt the message that I want to encrpyt.

Code:

```
$pgppath = "C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU/GnuPG";
putenv("PGPPATH=$pgppath");
$cmd = "echo '$msg' | '$pgppath'/gpg2.exe -e";
exec($cmd, $encrypted, $errorCode);
echo implode("\n", $encrypted);
mail($to, $subject, $encrypted[0]);
```

Thanks! I appreciate the help!

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: It doesn't encrypt the message. It's my first time working with PGP.

Comment: What does `$encrypted` contain? Where do you have this code from? (Not sure whether the pipe works the same on Windows as it does on Linux)

Comment: Encrypted should have the encrypted message. It's populated from the exec command.

Comment: Does the command work if you enter it manually into the console?

Answer (score 1):

Problem may be in '$pgppath'/gpg2.exe, it will be resolved to 'C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU/GnuPG'/gpg2.exe -e

Comment: +1.  This might work better?: `$cmd = "echo '$msg' | '$pgppath/gpg2.exe' -e";`

Comment: I did that and it still gave me the same result :(